# Get de Entry no funciona (python (tkinter))

Tags: python, tkinter

Necesito hacer el siguiente ejercicio, el problema es que cuando quiero usar el 
var.get() no me devuelve nada, no da error, solo no devuelve nada.
He probado a usarlo dentro del main y funciona, pero dentro de la funcion no, alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias.

```
"""
4. Una secuencia de ADN es una cadena compuesta de As, Ts, Cs y Gs. Escribe una aplicación
GUI en la cual se ingresa una secuencia de ADN, y cuando se hace clic en el botón Contar, se
cuenta y se visualiza el número de As, Ts, Cs y Gs en la ventana (vea la imagen a
continuación).
"""

from tkinter import *
ventana= Tk()

def buscaRufus(var,entradaTexto):
    As= str(var.get()).upper().count("AS")
    Ts= str(var.get()).upper().count("TS")
    Cs= str(var.get()).upper().count("CS")
    Gs= str(var.get()).upper().count("GS")

    textoFinal="Num As: " +str(As)+ " Num Ts: " +str(Ts)+ " Num Cs: " +str(Cs)+ " Num GS: " +str(Gs)   
    a= StringVar()
    a= "a"+var.get()
    entradaTexto.set(a)

if __name__=="__main__":
    #Variables globales
    var= StringVar()
    entradaTexto= StringVar()
    #Vista
    contenedor= Frame(ventana).pack()
    Entry= Entry(contenedor, borderwidth="4", textvariable=var).pack()

    boton= Button(contenedor, text="Busca", command=buscaRufus(var,entradaTexto)).pack()

    label= Label(contenedor, textvariable=entradaTexto).pack()


    ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Vale, desde el main tampoco va jajaja

Comment: Al parámetro `command` le estás pasando _el resultado de invocar_ la función `buscaRufus()`, pero lo que le tendrías que pasar es la propia función `buscaRufus`. Ya se ocupará Tk de llamarla cuando se pulse el botón. El problema es que no puedes especificarle qué parámetros ha de pasarle, por lo que tendrás que tirar de variables globales (aunque lo mejor sería que fueran todo métodos de una clase y en vez de variables globales usaran atributos del objeto).

Comment: Aparte de eso no has entendido bien el enunciado... En un ADN sólo aparecen las letras `A`, `T`, `G` y `C`, nunca la `S`, por lo que tus `.count()` nunca van a encontrar cosas como `AS`, `TS`,etc. La "s" que usa el problema es sólo para indicar el plural. "Cuantas Ts" quiere decir "Cuántas T", etc.

Comment: Ahhh, okey, todo listo, grácias, he metido una lambda para arreglarlo, se ha quedado así: boton= Button(contenedor, text="Busca", command= lambda:buscaRufus(var,entradaTexto)).pack()

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en el `command`, llamas a la función con parámetros, esto hace que se ejecute al iniciar el programa solamente. Si quieres pasar parámetros hazlo con una función lambda.

Sustituye en tu código el *botón* por lo siguiente:

```
boton= Button(contenedor, text="Busca", command= lambda x=var, y=entradaTexto: buscaRufus(x,y))
boton.pack()
```

No se exactamente que esperas de salida, por que tu variable `textoFinal` nunca se usa, pero el código de arriba pasa los parámetros a tu función, que es lo que pretendes.

Por cierto, te recomiendo primero crear el widget y después mostrarlo en otra línea diferente (ya sea con `pack()` o con `grid()`), esto ya que si lo tienes todo pegado en una línea cuando intentes llamar el widget estarás llamando al método `pack()` o `grid()`(en tu caso `pack()`). Es una buena practica que te ahorra dolores de cabeza en un futuro cuando tengas manejes *Frames* y *Canvas*.

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que hay veces hay error porque esta el .pack() donde el entry. Proba

```
entry = Entry(contenedor, borderwidth="4", textvariable=var)
entry.pack()
```